# Comparing XML with ActionScript 3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, loops, comparison

I have some fairly large XML files which I need to compare in Flash and then assign different scores for each node that matches. I don't have control over the XML files so I can't use node attributes or anything like that to store the point value. In the simplified example below I was thinking of using a multidimensional array to store the node location and then the point value similar to below. Though it doesn't return an error it is obviously not working the way I would like because the point value should only by 5. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var sourceXML:XML = 
            <root>
                <white>
                    <player>
                        <name>DOES NOT MATCH</name>
                        <sport>Basketball</sport>
                    </player>
                    <player>
                        <name>John Johnson</name>
                        <sport>Soccer</sport>
                    </player>
                    <player>
                        <name>James Anderson</name>
                        <sport>Tennis</sport>
                    </player>
                </white>
                <black>
                    <player>
                        <name>John Smith</name>
                        <sport>Soccer</sport>
                    </player>
                    <player>
                        <name>Frank Johnson</name>
                        <sport>Soccer</sport>
                    </player>
                    <player>
                        <name>Peter Jackson</name>
                        <sport>Baseball</sport>
                    </player>
                </black>
            </root>

    var comparedXML:XML = 
                <root>
                    <white>
                        <player>
                            <name>Steve Smith</name>
                            <sport>Basketball</sport>
                        </player>
                        <player>
                            <name>John Johnson</name>
                            <sport>Soccer</sport>
                        </player>
                        <player>
                            <name>James Anderson</name>
                            <sport>Tennis</sport>
                        </player>
                    </white>
                    <black>
                        <player>
                            <name>John Smith</name>
                            <sport>Soccer</sport>
                        </player>
                        <player>
                            <name>Frank Johnson</name>
                            <sport>Soccer</sport>
                        </player>
                        <player>
                            <name>Peter Jackson</name>
                            <sport>Baseball</sport>
                        </player>
                    </black>
                </root>

    trace(sourceXML.white.player.name[0]); //DOES NOT MATCH
    trace(comparedXML.white.player.name[0]); //Steve Smith

    var scored:Array = new Array();
    scored[0] = [".white.player.name[0]", "100"];
    scored[1] = [".white.player.name[1]", "1"];
    scored[2] = [".white.player.name[2]", "1"];
    scored[3] = [".white.player.sport[0]", "1"];
    scored[4] = [".white.player.sport[1]", "1"];
    scored[5] = [".white.player.sport[2]", "1"];

    var points:Number = 0;

    for(var i:int = 0; i < scored.length; i++)
    {
        if(sourceXML[scored[i][0]] == comparedXML[scored[i][0]])
        {
            points += Number(scored[i][1]);
        }
    }

    trace(points);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have it traverse multiple properties in XML the way you're trying here sourceXML[scored[i][0]]

Why not just store what they scored in the XML then in the loop just be stepping through both of the XML lists?  As is it seems like very hard to maintain code, each entry you add adds a lot of code.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like `if(sourceXML.white.player.name[0] == comparedXML.white.player.name[0]){points += 100}`

Comment: That's sort of what I was getting at except the points += value would also be stored in the XML.  I'm just trying to understand why the data needs to be separated with part of it in the XML and part of it in an Array, seems to arbitrarily complicate things,  you could define it all in one or the other, alternatively if you need to have some in XML and some in an array treat combining those lists as it's own problem first then the iteration/comparison step is easy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I am not generating the XML so I cannot add anything to it or alter it in any way. Also it gets fairly complicated with namespaces and several thousand nodes that get to be deeply nested. Not all the nodes are scored but a lot are so I guess I am trying to avoid writing hundreds or thousands of if...then comparisons to directly compare/score the values but that might be the only way.

Comment: I think if you write up more generally what your problem is instead of presenting it in this way you'll get a better response.  Good to show what you're trying to do to solve the problem but I don't understand what the general problem is and I think there's probably an easier solution.  Just present your data or explain how you get it a bit more and I'll try to revise my answer.